# res.status is undefined within a promise function

Tags: express, promise, routes

Here is my function in a file called 'queries.js' to query the database and return the results as a json object

```
function getUsers(req,res) {
  db.any('select * from table')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response); \\prints out JSON results directly from database
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: response,
          message: 'Retrieved all data'
      });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

module.exports = {getUsers:getUsers};
```

And here is my express route that should be sending the data returned from the above function to a URL allowing me to fetch it from the front end.

```
db = require('./queries');

app.get('', function(res,req) {
  db.getUsers();
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that in the first function "res" is undefined, so when I try to call res.status, it throws an error and doesn't go on to execute the rest of the code that should send the data to the endpoint.

Any ideas as to why res is undefined in the context of the promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing params in `getUsers` may help.

```
db = require('./queries');

app.get('', function(res,req) {
  db.getUsers(req,res);
});
```

Comment: That was quick! Glad it was something dumb that I missed and not a flaw with the logic. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about your project. But I really recommend using typescipt if you can. TS will reduce your debugging time significantly. And such error will be caught right away.